# Creating a balloon tooltip for a label in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I have a label as such:

```
<asp:Label ID="LblToolTip" runat="server" Text="What's this?" ToolTip="Note: The id appears on the confirmation email."></asp:Label>
```

I tried to follow tutorials online to get a tooltip with a balloon appear, but I get this error. How can I fix?

[image]

Comment: use https://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css/

Comment: @rashfmnb Oh this is nice! Thanks.

Comment: You can't mix controls that belong to System.Windows.Forms and System.Web.UI

Comment: @rene I know, but I was hoping for an alternative for this issue. So there is no way in Visual Studio to create the balloon effect with an asp label?

Answer (score 0):

use this [link](http://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css) for showing tooltips

```
<button data-balloon="Whats up!" data-balloon-pos="up">Hover me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely. I was hoping there was something already built-in with Visual Studio though.

Comment: @rashfmnb Would you show an example here rather than a single link?

Comment: both of you are right but the thing is this that i cant paste the whole css,html and other dependencies of ballon.css over here that's why i just paste the link if it's few lines of code than definitely i will post the code along with the link